# Função JavaScript para zeros à esquerda com MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um loop dentro do meu arquivo cshtml. Esse loop tem uma variável `i` e eu a uso para compor um nome de acordo com a posição dela no loop, tipo  `txtNome1`, `txtNome2`, `txtNome3` e assim por diante.

Preciso fazer com a variável seja composta com zeros à esquerda para que o nome menor que 10 fique assim: `txtNome01`, `txtNome02`, `txtNome03` e assim por diante.

Como fazer isso dentro do loop no arquivo `cshtml`? O meu problema está em como usar. Veja abaixo parte do meu for(loop). Eu preciso já compor as variáveis que irão completar o nome.

```
    string 
        nm,dia,mes,ano,sexo,numpassaporte,
        diavalidade, mesvalidade,
        anovalidade, paisemissao = "";

    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        nm            = "txtNome" + i;
        dia           = "txtDia" + i;
        mes           = "txtMes" + i;
        ano           = "txtAno" + i;
        sexo          = "txtSexo" + i;
        numpassaporte = "txtPassaporte" + i;
        diavalidade   = "txtDiaVal" + i;
        mesvalidade   = "txtMesVal" + i;
        anovalidade   = "txtAnoVal" + i;
        paisemissao   = "txtPaisEmissao" + i;
```

Falei JavaScript, mas pode ser qualquer coisa, desde que não seja no code behind para dar mais performance ao site.

Comment: Se achou sua resposta marque uma delas como solução do seu problema..

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método [`String.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para preencher seus números com zeros à esquerda.

```
"2".padStart(5, 0);  // "00002"
"123".padStart(8, 0);  // "00000123"
```

Caso a [compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pad-start-end) seja um problema, a [documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) tem um exemplo de *polyfill*, ou você pode ver [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998822/1284458) do SOEn que têm uma função que faz o *padding*. Veja o código:

```
function lpad(num, size) {
    let s = num + "";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Se você souber que o número não vai ultrapassar N dígitos, você também poderia fazer:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    let s = "000000000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a regra for ter apenas 2 dígitos, pode fazer assim:

```
var sufixo = i < 10 ? "0" + i : i;
```

e depois concatenar com os nomes das variáveis:

```
nm            = "txtNome" + sufixo;
dia           = "txtDia" + sufixo;
mes           = "txtMes" + sufixo;
ano           = "txtAno" + sufixo;
sexo          = "txtSexo" + sufixo;
numpassaporte = "txtPassaporte" + sufixo;
diavalidade   = "txtDiaVal" + sufixo;
mesvalidade   = "txtMesVal" + sufixo;
anovalidade   = "txtAnoVal" + sufixo;
paisemissao   = "txtPaisEmissao" + sufixo;
```

Com isso tudo dentro do `for`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função abaixo ([fonte](http://phpjs.org/functions/str_pad/)) para preenche uma string para um certo tamanho com outra string:

```
function str_pad(input, pad_length, pad_string, pad_type) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/str_pad/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: Michael White (http://getsprink.com)
  //    input by: Marco van Oort
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //   example 1: str_pad('Kevin van Zonneveld', 30, '-=', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
  //   returns 1: '-=-=-=-=-=-Kevin van Zonneveld'
  //   example 2: str_pad('Kevin van Zonneveld', 30, '-', 'STR_PAD_BOTH');
  //   returns 2: '------Kevin van Zonneveld-----'

  var half = '',
    pad_to_go;

  var str_pad_repeater = function(s, len) {
    var collect = '',
      i;

    while (collect.length < len) {
      collect += s;
    }
    collect = collect.substr(0, len);

    return collect;
  };

  input += '';
  pad_string = pad_string !== undefined ? pad_string : ' ';

  if (pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_LEFT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_RIGHT' && pad_type !== 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
    pad_type = 'STR_PAD_RIGHT';
  }
  if ((pad_to_go = pad_length - input.length) > 0) {
    if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_LEFT') {
      input = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go) + input;
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_RIGHT') {
      input = input + str_pad_repeater(pad_string, pad_to_go);
    } else if (pad_type === 'STR_PAD_BOTH') {
      half = str_pad_repeater(pad_string, Math.ceil(pad_to_go / 2));
      input = half + input + half;
      input = input.substr(0, pad_length);
    }
  }

  return input;
}
```

E dentro do seu loop, aplique a função str_pad para completar com zeros a esquerda:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        i_pad = str_pad(i, 2, '0', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
        nm            = "txtNome" + i_pad;
        dia           = "txtDia" + i_pad;
        (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Em javascript vc pode usar `slice` desde que vc saiba quantidade de caracteres

```
nm = 'txtNome' + ("0"+i).slice(-2); // txtNome01
```

Eu fiz um exemplo em [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEXCool/Ej935/)

Uma abordagem que eu tb faria é:

```
Number.prototype.leadingZeros = function (n) {
  var z = n - this.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(z<0?0:z).join("0") + this;
}
```

Que pode ser usado assim:

```
nm = 'txtNome' + i.leadingZeros(2); // txtNome01
```

Um exemplo em [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEXCool/Ej935/5/)

Em c# vc pode usar algo assim:

```
public static string leadingZeros(int n, int s){
    return n.ToString(String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("0", s<0?0:s).ToArray()));
}
```

ex:

```
 nm = "txtNome" + leadingZeros(i, 2);
```

ou

```
 nm = "txtNome" + i.ToString("00");
```